# How to Write Hibernate HQL query using join?

Tags: mysql, oracle, hql

i'm new to write `HQl` query please help me.. Actually my `SQL Query` is have 5 tables i.e `COURSE`,`SKILLSET`,`TIMETABLE`,`INTREST`,`USER`

```
select
 (select count(*) from intrest) AS 
    NoAttends,course.NAME,course.TYPE,user.FIRSTNAME,user.LASTNAME,skill.COURSE_CONT,
   skill.TEACH_EXP,tt.CLASS_DUR,tt.COURSE_DUR,tt.DATE_TIME from COURSE course 
   inner join SKILLSET skill on
   skill.course_id=course.s_id 
   inner join USER user on 
   user.s_id=skill.user_id 
   inner join TIMETABLE tt on
   tt.course_id=course.s_id
   where course.name IN ('course') 
   ORDER BY course.name LIMIT 10;
```

please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like below. . . .  .

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3 
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN t1.someGroupMemebers t2 
JOIN t2.someUser t3 WHERE t3.username = 'blah blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JPA for Hibernate it is very easy for ex:

```
    entityManager.createQuery("select cd from CourseDetailsVO cd join cd.course.keywords k where k.keyword in (:courseName) and cd.startDate between (:sDate) and (:eDate)", CourseDetailsVO.class);
setParameter("courseName", searchVO.getName())..
...
```

EntityManager will do the handling..